# Flutter - A TextEditingController was used after being disposed - Provider

Tags: flutter, exception, dispose, flutter-provider

I have a List of custom widgets that contain a TextFormField and use a TextEditingController which I initialize in the initState() function of the custom widget. I have wrapped the custom Widget in a Dismissible Widget to remove them from a list using the onDismissed function. This all looks like this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.nameController = TextEditingController(text: widget.initialName);
    widget.amountController = TextEditingController(text: widget.initialAmount);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.nameController.dispose();
    widget.amountController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CreateOrEditRecipe createOrEditRecipe =
        Provider.of<CreateOrEditRecipe>(context);

    return Dismissible(
      key: Key(widget.id),
      background: buildSwipeActionRight(),
      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        createOrEditRecipe.removeIngredientCard(widget.id);
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 60,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: widget.nameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Foo",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

```
removeIngredientCard(String toRemove) {
    _ingredientCards.removeWhere((element) => element.id == toRemove);

    notifyListeners();
}
```

After removing the UI is updated using notifyListeners().

This removes the custom Widget from the list correctly and the UI updates correctly aswell, but if I now select the TextFormField of the last of the remaining widgets in the list, I get an error.

This error does not appear when I remove the last widget of the list and then try to select the TextFormField of the last widget of the remaining ones.

Any ideas where the problem might be?